# how to know which version of my javascript file a client is using

Tags: javascript, monitoring, metrics

I would like to know which versions of my script my clients are using.

The client insert the javascript to include my script in its html page, the script is served throught CDN.

I'd like to know when the script is executed, on which domain, which version.

Is there any application doing this?

I'd like to see the script update propagation, to be sure that all clients have updated their page.

Comment: Is that a script you wrote or is it an external library?

Comment: A script I wrote. So I can Embed a library to log events, I guess, but I haven't found any. All I can find are error traking tools such as sentry.

Comment: How about include it in the url ? Something like this
<script src="https://yourdomain.com/cdn/1.0.2/script.js"></script>